# Can't access to inner nodes in JSON message - IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to access "node" node for this JSON message:

```
{
   "nodes": [
      {
         "node": {
            "title": "Jornada del Fútbol Profesional contra el hambre",
            "description": "
             "image": "",
            "fecha": "",
            "nid": "",
            "noticia_relacionada_1_path": "",
            "noticia_relacionada_2_path": "",
            "image_small_2": ""
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

With this code:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue]; 

NSDictionary *nodes = [results objectForKey:@"nodes"];
```

results dictionary has 1 key result. nodes dictionary has 10 keys result. But when I try to access for node with all of this options, I got no results:

```
NSString *node = [nodes valueForKey:@"node"];

NSArray *nodeArray = [nodes objectForKey:@"node"];

NSDictionary *nodeDic = [nodes objectForKey:@"node"];
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you retrieve with

```
NSDictionary *nodes = [results objectForKey:@"nodes"];
```

is not a dictionary, it is an array of dictionaries, each with one entry with the key "node".  To get the first node:

```
NSArray *nodes = [results objectForKey:@"nodes"];

NSDictionary firstNodeDict = [[nodes objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"node"];
```